# Using JOOQ DSLContext.transactionResult with setLocal

Tags: jooq, r2dbc

I am trying to set a local variable on Postgresql by using reactive way inside dslContext.transactionResult.
I want to keep the user_id, the id of the user who changed the product table, in the product history table with the help of trigger.

My trigger function for product history table uses this script inside it to fetch user_id variable.

```
DECLARE user_id text := current_setting('user_id', true);
```

Actually i want to create the same behaviour of this sql script by using jooq reactive transaction support.

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL user_id = 'XXXXXXXXX';
insert into .....
COMMIT;
```

But the following jooq code does not works, the user_id variable does not take the value of it in product history table.

```
  public Mono<Product> upsertProduct(Long productId, String name, String userId) {
    return dslContext.transactionResult(configuration -> {
      DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(configuration);
      return Mono.from(ctx.setLocal(DSL.name("user_id"), DSL.value(userId)))
                 .flatMap(result -> Mono.from(ctx.insertInto(PRODUCT)
                                                 .set(PRODUCT.ID, productId)
                                                 .set(PRODUCT.NAME, name)
                                                 .onConflictOnConstraint(Keys.PRODUCT_PK)
                                                 .doUpdate()
                                                 .set(PRODUCT.NAME, name)
                                                 .returning())
                                        .map(dbRecord -> dbRecord.into(Product.class)));
    });
  }
```

I expected it should set local variable user_id in product history table while saving the product record to product table. But it does not set local variable so i can not see user_id field in product history table even though it saves the product record to product table.

Please could you help me about whether the reactive of setLocal is been supporting or not? Because when i try to use non-reactive way by using dslContext.transaction.. it works and i can see the local variable on product history table.

#### jOOQ Version

3.16.5

#### Database product and version

PostgreSQL 11.18 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit

#### Java Version

17

#### OS Version

macOS Big Sur [Version 11.6]

#### JDBC driver name and version

org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.6

Answer (score 3):

### On the design of R2DBC

As per the R2DBC specification of the underlying [`Result::getRowsUpdated`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/1.0.0.RELEASE/io/r2dbc/spi/Result.html#getRowsUpdated--), a query that doesn't return any update counts doesn't return anything at all:

> Returns the number of rows updated by a query against a database. May be empty if the query did not update any rows.

This is different from JDBC, where [`Statement::executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) always returns an `int` value, e.g. `0`, even if there was nothing to return.

In fact, when you use JDBC in a streaming mode via [`Statement::execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)), then it also doesn't return an update count for every statement in a statement batch, in case you're sending multiple `;` separated statements to the server, e.g. in MySQL or SQL Server.

Now, jOOQ doesn't do anything special. It just inherits R2DBC's behaviour here. If the R2DBC [`Statement`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/1.0.0.RELEASE/io/r2dbc/spi/Statement.html) doesn't produce any results, then neither can jOOQ's [`RowCountQuery`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/RowCountQuery.html)

### How does this impact your query

The problem in your query is that you're using `flatMap()`:

```java
Mono.from(ctx.setLocal(DSL.name("user_id"), DSL.value(userId)))
    .flatMap(result -> Mono.from(ctx.insertInto(PRODUCT) // ...
```

But the first query doesn't produce anything, so your `flatMap()` lambda is never called! What you should do instead is use `then()`:

```java
Mono.from(ctx.setLocal(DSL.name("user_id"), DSL.value(userId)))
    .then(Mono.from(ctx.insertInto(PRODUCT) // ...
```