# Spring webflux jooq setLocal not working with select

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, jooq, r2dbc-postgresql

I am trying to set a local variable on Postgresql by using like below source code

**DSLContext**

```kotlin
@Bean(name = ["r2dbcDsl"])
fun r2dbcDsl(): DSLContext {
    return DSL.using(connectionFactory)
}
```

**ReactiveTransactionManager**

```kotlin
@Bean
fun reactiveTransactionManager(): ReactiveTransactionManager {
    return R2dbcTransactionManager(connectionFactory)
}
```

**function**

```kotlin
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "reactiveTransactionManager")
fun select(): Flux<Map<String, Any>> {
    return Mono.just(r2dbcDsl.setLocal(name("enable_sort"), value(false)))
        .flatMapMany {
            Flux.from(
                r2dbcDsl
                    .select(field("current_setting('enable_sort')"))
            )
        }
        .map { it.intoMap() }
}
```

But, return of function is like below

**actual response**

```json
[
    {
        "current_setting('enable_sort')": "on"
    }
]
```

**expected response**

```json
[
    {
        "current_setting('enable_sort')": "off"
    }
]
```

**dependencies**

```
spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.7.3
spring-boot-starter-jooq:2.7.3
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.7.3
io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.13.RELEASE
```

So, please let me know how to use DSLContext **select** function with **setLocal**

And i already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75758127/using-jooq-dslcontext-transactionresult-with-setlocal) and changed my code like this

```kotlin
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "reactiveTransactionManager")
fun select(): Flux<Map<String, Any>> {
    return Mono.just(r2dbcDsl.setLocal(name("enable_sort"), value(false)))
        .thenMany(
            Flux.from(
                r2dbcDsl
                    .select(field("current_setting('enable_sort')"))
            )
        ).map { it.intoMap() }
}
```

but actual response is same.

Comment: It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75758127/521799). In short, `setLocal()` doesn't return any update count in R2DBC, so you can't use `Mono.flatMap()` here. Use `Mono.then()`

Comment: Are you certain that Spring's `@Transactional` aspect is propagated to jOOQ correctly?

Comment: Except for the main codes written above, i didn't do extra something. Maybe something have to do for @Transactional aspect is propagated to jOOQ?